# how to update a record without worrying about primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In ActiveRecord how can we update a record without worrying/knowing primary key.

If I do

```
Address.update(15, :user_name => 'Samuel')
```

it corresponds to

```
UPDATE addresses set user_name = 'Samuel' where id = 15
```

but what if i want to do:

```
UPDATE addresses set user_name = 'Samuel' where cid = 15
```

what will be the ActiveRecord equivalent of that??

I tried:

```
Address.update({:cid => 15}, :user_name => 'Samuel')
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
a = Address.find_by_cid(15)
a.user_name = 'Samuel'
a.save
```

Comment: agreed.. there has to be a better answer.

Answer (score 47):

Use the `update_all` class method:

```
Address.where(:cid => 15).update_all(user_name : 'Samuel')
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: this should be the answer.  One hit to the database, and almost zero network traffic.  Nice.

Comment: Important note: "It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Values passed to `update_all` will not go through ActiveRecord’s type-casting behavior. It should receive only values that can be passed as-is to the SQL database."

Answer (score 11):

To clarify on @typeoneerror's answer, just use `update_all` on an ActiveRecord::Relation object rather than a record object:

```
ModelName.where(:unique_id => x).update_all(:name => "x")
```

Comment: You should improve his answer instead of create a new

Comment: This answer was written when the other answer didn't have an example, only the link to the method.

Answer (score -5):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002273

Comment: Please provide some additional information besides the link. What if the URL changes?